# php: what is meant by non-associative Operator

Tags: php

I was reading [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) understand php Operator Precedence and Associativity

I've following list of Operators that are  non-associative:

```
clone , new, instanceof, < <= > >=,  == != === !== <> <=>
```

Why these  Operators that are  non-associative ? please help me to understand them with good examples covering all varieties of these operator such as: **clone , new, instanceof, <,  ==** .thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

Comment: I don't think the post Uchiha chose is a good answer for what user5006768 is asking. I read through it and I can find nothing about what associative or non-associative operators really mean.